# sql server 2005 express and sql server 2008 developer edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to install sql server 2005 express and sql server 2008 developer edition in one machine ?

Any gotchas ?

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you should be able to without any problems.  Sometimes they do occur though.  Take a look at this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/b4e6ef94-40ef-4c96-b4e7-e91f7dfca690) for some potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, one of them needs to be a named instance (that is the only gotcha )

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have SQL Server 2005 Express and 2008 Enterprise on my machine. I have the 2005 instance named.

I haven't run into any issues yet but you should look at Sev's link for potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, as long as you install the 2005 version first - I wasn't able to re-install SQL 2005 once I had SQL 2008 on my dev machine.

Marc